# Как создать/перезаписать свойства и группы свойств файла со Structured Storage API?

Tags: c#, c++

Работаю с программой [SolidEdge](https://solidedge.siemens.com/ru/) от Siemens. Мне необходимо читать/создавать/редактировать свойства и группы свойств файлов. Для этих целей имеется официальное COM API, но оно требует установленную SolidEdge с лицензией и помимо этого работает очень медленно. Но так как файлы программы являются составными ([Compound Files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Stg/compound-files)) и поддерживают API структурированного хранилища ([Structured Storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Stg/structured-storage-start-page)), то это можно использовать для решения задачи. Для чтения свойств файла уже существует [SolidEdge.Community.Reader](https://github.com/SolidEdgeCommunity/SolidEdge.Community.Reader), с помощью которого можно читать свойства файлов не используя COM интерфейс, но он поддерживает только чтение свойств. На [форуме Siemens](https://community.plm.automation.siemens.com/t5/Solid-Edge-Developer-Forum/Writing-to-Solid-Edge-File-Properties-without-SE-installed/td-p/442302) автор библиотеки [предлагает](https://community.plm.automation.siemens.com/t5/Solid-Edge-Developer-Forum/Writing-to-Solid-Edge-File-Properties-without-SE-installed/m-p/442585/highlight/true#M9294) добавить функциональность создания/редактирования свойств, если это необходимо, но каким образом не уточняет. Как бы то ни было, с помощью Structured Storage API решить проблему возможно. В этом я убедился используя [Structured Storage Viewer](http://www.mitec.cz/ssv.html), с помощью которого можно редактировать свойства файлов, создавать группы свойств и т.д.. После продолжительного поиска ничего конкретного для работы со составными файлами с помощью C# я не нашёл. В связи с чем имеются пару вопросов:

- каким образом создавать/редактировать/удалять группы свойств в составных файлах?
- каким образом создавать/редактировать/удалять свойства в составных файлах?
- в идеале хотелось бы узнать, каким образом расширить функционал библиотеки [SolidEdge.Community.Reader](https://github.com/SolidEdgeCommunity/SolidEdge.Community.Reader) для возможности записи свойств?

---

#### Ссылки по теме

- [вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55581942)
- [Compound Files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Stg/compound-files)
- [Structured Storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Stg/structured-storage-start-page)
- [SolidEdge.Community.Reader на GitHub](https://github.com/SolidEdgeCommunity/SolidEdge.Community.Reader)
- [Structured Storage Viewer](http://www.mitec.cz/ssv.html)
- [OpenMcdf на GitHub](https://github.com/ironfede/openmcdf)

P.S.: [файл](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xqs6doxb23sswm/Test.par?dl=0) SolidEdge для тестов.

Answer (score 5):

Вот пример записи значения строкового свойства в набор свойств Structured Storage:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        static extern int StgOpenStorageEx(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwcsName, 
            uint grfMode,
            uint stgfmt, 
            uint grfAttrs,
            IntPtr  pStgOptions, 
            IntPtr reserved2, 
            [In] ref Guid riid,
            out IPropertySetStorage ppObjectOpen);                

        const uint STGM_DIRECT = 0;
        const uint STGM_READWRITE = 0x2;
        const uint STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE = 0x10;
        const uint STGFMT_ANY = 4;
        const uint VT_LPWSTR = 31;
        const uint PID_FIRST_USABLE = 2;
        const uint STGC_DEFAULT = 0;
        const uint PRSPEC_LPWSTR = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPropertySetStorage pPropSetStg = null;
            IPropertyStorage pPropStg = null;
            int hr;
            PROPSPEC propspec=new PROPSPEC();
            PROPVARIANT propvarWrite=new PROPVARIANT();
            Guid guidPropertySetStorage = typeof(IPropertySetStorage).GUID;

            string path = "c:\\Test\\Test.stg"; //путь к файлу            
            Guid fmtid = Guid.Parse("F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9"); //GUID набора свойств

            try
            {
                //открываем файл
                hr = StgOpenStorageEx(path, STGM_READWRITE | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, STGFMT_ANY,
                    0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, ref guidPropertySetStorage, out pPropSetStg);
                if (hr != 0) throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(hr);

                //открываем набор свойств
                pPropSetStg.Open(fmtid, STGM_DIRECT | STGM_READWRITE | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, out pPropStg);

                //имя свойства...
                propspec.ulKind = PRSPEC_LPWSTR;
                propspec.unionmember = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("Property");

                //значение свойства...
                propvarWrite.vt = (ushort)VT_LPWSTR;
                propvarWrite.unionmember = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("Value");

                //записываем свойство
                pPropStg.WriteMultiple(1, ref propspec, ref propvarWrite, PID_FIRST_USABLE);
                pPropStg.Commit(STGC_DEFAULT);                                
            }
            finally
            {
                //освобождение ресурсов
                if (propspec.unionmember != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(propspec.unionmember);
                if (propvarWrite.unionmember != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(propvarWrite.unionmember);
                if (pPropSetStg != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pPropSetStg);
                if (pPropStg != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pPropStg);
            }

        }

    }        

    [ComImport]
    [Guid("00000138-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IPropertyStorage
    {
        void a();
        void WriteMultiple(uint cpspec, ref PROPSPEC rgpspec, ref PROPVARIANT rgpropvar, uint propidNameFirst);
        void b( );
        void c( );
        void d();
        void e();
        void Commit(uint grfCommitFlags);
        void f();
        void g();
        void h( );
        void x();
        void y();
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PROPSPEC
    {       
        public uint ulKind;
        public IntPtr unionmember;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PROPVARIANT
    {        
        public ushort vt;        
        public byte wReserved1;        
        public byte wReserved2;        
        public uint wReserved3;
        public IntPtr unionmember;
    }       

    [ComImport]
    [Guid("0000013A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IPropertySetStorage
    {
        void Create(ref Guid rfmtid, ref Guid pClsid,  uint grfFlags,  uint grfMode, out IPropertyStorage ppprstg);
        void Open( ref Guid rfmtid,  uint grfMode, out IPropertyStorage ppprstg);
        void Delete(ref Guid rfmtid);
        void f();
    }  


}
```

Создание нового набора свойств:

```
pPropSetStg.Create(fmtid, new Guid(), 0,STGM_DIRECT | STGM_READWRITE | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, out pPropStg);
```

Источник: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Stg/writeread-sample

Comment: Большое спасибо за уделённое время моей проблеме! Но каким образом добавить свой набор свойств и редактировать свойства в него входящие? Имеется ввиду те свойства, которые отображаются на вкладке "OLE Properties" программы Structured Storage eXplorer при открытии файла Test.par и клике на группе свойств "DocumentSummaryInformation"?

Comment: @XelaNimed добавил код для создания нового набора. Редактирование - также как и добавление, просто указать имя существующего свойства, и оно перезапишется

Comment: В прикреплённом файле SolidEdge имеется пользовательские свойства с именами "IntCustomProperty", "TextCustomProperty", "Date CustomProperty" и "Bool CustomProperty".  Эти свойства не отображаются в программе Structured Storage Viewer, но видны на вкладке OLE Properties в Structured Storage eXplorer, входящем в репозиторий OpenMcdf. Каким образом с помощью приведённого примера изменить эти свойства?

Comment: Попробуйте поискать эти свойства в другом propery set - https://github.com/SolidEdgeCommunity/SolidEdge.Community.Reader/blob/b8b72788f2629ed9aad1f8c055a0ecf50f4f2723/src/SolidEdge.Community.Reader/Native/Constants.cs#L84